# How do you hard wire a garbage disposal?

Tags: electrical, wiring, garbage-disposal

I do not have a dishwasher. There was no existing garbage disposal and there is no plug under the sink. I'm trying to hard wire a garbage disposal there. I want to create a light switch off an existing plug and wire the garbage disposal to the light switch.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant for you, but if your house has a septic system you should make sure it's properly sized for a garbage disposal. Garbage disposals add a significant load to a septic system.

Comment: @HenryJackson- what are you putting in your sink?

Answer (score 3):

If this receptacle you are referring to is serving the kitchen counter you CANNOT use that to feed a disposal. Kitchen counter circuits cannot be used to feed fixed appliances.

You will need to run a new feed to the disposal, preferably a dedicated circuit from the panel.